# empty results displaying count as -1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, sigma-grid-control

We are displaying count of results displayed based on "from & to date" search, we are facing issue that when there is empty results, than its displaying "-1" as result, but we want to display as "0"

html code is

```
<div class="delete_grid" >

<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
<input type="text"  id="post_at" name="post_at"  />  
<input type="text"  id="post_at_to_date" value=""name="post_at_to_date"  />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" id="searchButton">

</form>

</div>
```

javascript code is

```
var gridOption={
    container : 'myGrid',
};

var mygrid=new Sigma.Grid(gridOption);
Sigma.Util.onLoad( Sigma.Grid.render(mygrid) );

$(".delete_grid").append("Number  of  Designs  Sold : "+mygrid.dataset.getSize());
```

we are using sigma plugin : http://pastebin.com/ftfL6qnU

Comment: I have not used `sigma` but `indexOf()` is a common function that returns `-1` when it doesn't find anything. And `indexOf()` is often used for finding or counting things. Try searching for occurrences of that in your code or the library functions you are using.

Comment: yes, we have indexof code in plugin,  can you please check plugin code here : http://pastebin.com/ftfL6qnU

Comment: i found 4 occurances, what i need to do now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you're getting `-1` exactly, I'm guessing here maybe: `mygrid.dataset.getSize()`?

In any case, you can probably use a [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
So let's say you need it there, use this: `mygrid.dataset.getSize()<0?0:mygrid.dataset.getSize()`

The complete line would become:

```
$(".delete_grid").append("Number  of  Designs  Sold : "+(mygrid.dataset.getSize()<0?0:mygrid.dataset.getSize()));
```

- When `mygrid.dataset.getSize()` is less then `0`, the value is set to `0`.
  Otherwise, the value of `mygrid.dataset.getSize()` is used.
- Notice that in the complete line, I wrapped the ternary operator in parentheses. It might not be strictly necessary, but when you're unsure or when it improves readability, I always prefer that.